# How to verify that the invisible_captcha is actually working well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, captcha

I'm using https://github.com/markets/invisible_captcha for my app on Heroku. How can I verify that it's actually working? Is there a way to simulate a behaviour of a bot and see the gem in action?

Comment: I like your dogs :)

Comment: @Vasif, yeah, they're great.

Comment: Did you see [this issue](https://github.com/markets/invisible_captcha/issues/3) on their github? Not sure if it's what you need, but maybe worth a shot?

Comment: @maxpleaner, yes. but for some reason it won't trigger for an ajax action. why?

Comment: because it might help you solve your question - i was just throwing something out there, have no idea,